# Brain DropIn UI shows error "Cannot read property "render" of undefined"

Tags: javascript, braintree

I have integrated the braintree Drop-IN UI for a few months now when suddenly I see this error:

[image: braintree Drop-in UI shows JS error]

This error is only shown in the Drop-In UI, I do not see it in the dev console. I use the latest JS API (1.9.4.).

Anybody that had similar issues lately and knows how to cope with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug. It is simply not a good idea to name one of your own fields "paypal" when using the drop-in UI. D'oh!

Comment: I can't found the way to get payload noune of paypal

Comment: I am getting the same issue @armin